# How to set default answer button in java MessageDialog.openQuestion?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, jface

I am writing an eclipse plugin and I am using MessageDialog.openQuestion to pop up a question. The default answer is "Yes" but I want it to be "no".
how do I do that?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that using the `openQuestion` method. Instead you will have to construct the `MessageDialog` using one of the constructors:

```
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(shell, "title", null, "message",           
    MessageDialog.QUESTION, 1, IDialogConstants.YES_LABEL, IDialogConstants.NO_LABEL);

int buttonPressed = dialog.open();
```

The `1` is the index of the default button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the defaultIndex attribute of the MessageDialog constructor.

*(Give a look at the [docs](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/MessageDialog.html#MessageDialog(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell,%20java.lang.String,%20org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)))*